# I want to allow an xml file concurrent read accesses

Tags: c++, xml, concurrency, msxml

I want to allow an xml document, that contains some configuration items, concurrent read-accesses (no write access) from several machines on a domain.

Could a simple DOMDocument30 be just what I need.
Or do you think FreeThreadedDOMDocument xml document template should be sufficient.

Or do you think of other xml document types I should be aware of.

In advance thx.

Comment: Don't share a readonly XML document as COM component. Unnessesarily slow and brittle. Read the file from each machine separately instead.

Comment: There are no so many accesses so as to consider any optimization consideration. It would be a shame not to use the simple API `IXMLDOMDocument::load();` without the little hassle of loading the file myself, reading the string, then passing it to the IXMLDocument created. Though I am not sure of myself, that's why I ask. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeThreadedDOMDocument is thread-safe in terms of reading. You can use this COM component in your project.